# Problemas ao abrir o VLC e Executar outra def

Tags: python-3.x

Pessoal estou criando um sistema que irá falar e ouvir o usuário, basicamente ele roda um video e o cara tem que responder (um quiz)

```
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Segue a parte do código:

```
 for i in range(0, questions):
    _playVideo('voice', ('video_0' + str(i)))
    _record(i)
```

Basicamente ocorre o seguinte: Quando o usuário iniciar o app.py ele vai rodar um video com uma pergunta, e ele tem que responder, assim que ele der a resposta (por voz) ele abre a segunda pergunta e assim até a ultima...

Alguém já passou por isso??

OBS: Estou usando o raspberry PI 3 não sei se influencia em algo

Comment: Só com o que colocou na pergunta ficará impossível entender o problema. Você precisa fazer que a aplicação ouça o usuário mesmo durante a execução do vídeo? Você utilizou threads para isso? Se sim, como fez? Se não, poderia detalhar melhor o problema? Quais as implementações das funções `_playVideo` e `_record`?

Comment: Anderson, acabou que eu já consegui resolver rsrs, mas respondendo a sua perugunta, não ele só ouve o usuário depois do video acabar, estou usando o SpeechRecognition da Google para ouvir o usuário no _record

Comment: @WallaceBruno Se você conseguiu resolver a pergunta, poste a resposta para que as pessoas que vierem aqui depois saberem como foi feito e tentar replicar se for do interesse delas. O intuito do SOPT é justamente deixar o registro de como as coisas são feitas por aqui, ainda de mais uma solução como a sua que parece bem interessante.

Answer (score 0):

Segue a solução que eu achei para executar 1 video de cada vez conforme a fala do usuário:

Abaixo tem uma função chamada _play() que toca os arquivos de áudio:

```
def _playVideo(file):
    os.system('vlc /home/pi/bot/audio/voice/' + file + '.mp4 -f --quiet')
```

Esse "file" é passado conforme a solicitação do usuário (usando Watson ele passa a intenção do conversation)

A chamado da função é feita em cima do número de perguntas que temos (no caso são 18) então ficou assim:

```
questions = 18
for i in range(1, questions):
  if (i = 1):
    _playVideo(str(1))
  else:
    _play(conversation_return)
```